# python inheritance : new class don't initialize properly

Tags: python, inheritance

I am writing a class called XGB, which inherits from XGBClassifier (from the python library xgboost.sklearn). I wrote an *init* function and a fit one, shown here :

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from balanceSmote import BalanceSmote   
from balance import Balance


class XGB(XGBClassifier):

def __init__(self,learning_rate=0.5, max_depth=3,colsample_bytree=0.5,n_estimators=300,
             frac=None,k_neighbors=None,m_neighbors=None,out_step=None):

    # These are the additional arguments that are not in XGBClassifier
    if k_neighbors:
        self.balancingStrategy = 'smote'
        self.k_neighbors = k_neighbors
        self.m_neighbors = m_neighbors
        self.out_step = out_step
    elif frac :
        self.balancingStrategy = 'normal'
        self.frac = frac
    else:
        self.balancingStrategy = 'false'

    # Utilize the motherClass
    super(XGB,self).__init__(seed=500, 
                        learning_rate = learning_rate, 
                        max_depth = max_depth,
                        colsample_bytree = colsample_bytree, 
                        n_estimators = n_estimators)
```

Here is my test code :

```
xgb4 = XGB(learning_rate = 0.1, max_depth = 3, colsample_bytree = 1, n_estimators = 1000)

xgb4.fit(trainData,trainLabel)
```

The initialization seems to go well, but when I try to use fit() (which is a method inherited from XGBClassifier), I have an error message telling me a parameter is missing :

```
File "<ipython-input-3-47344b7fbc76>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('/Users/celsloaner/Project/SPUDS/code/testSpark.py', wdir='/Users/celsloaner/Project/SPUDS/code')

File "/anaconda/envs/SPUDS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/anaconda/envs/SPUDS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/celsloaner/Project/SPUDS/code/testSpark.py", line 50, in <module>
xgb4.fit(predictor.trainData,predictor.trainLabel)

File "/anaconda/envs/SPUDS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 396, in fit
xgb_options = self.get_xgb_params()

File "/anaconda/envs/SPUDS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 177, in get_xgb_params
xgb_params = self.get_params()

File "/anaconda/envs/SPUDS/lib/python3.5/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py", line 169, in get_params
if params['missing'] is np.nan:

KeyError: 'missing'
```

The problem comes from inside the mother class, which should have been initialized properly. Here is the mother class problematic function :

```
def get_params(self, deep=False):
    """Get parameter.s"""
    params = super(XGBModel, self).get_params(deep=deep)
    if params['missing'] is np.nan:
        params['missing'] = None  # sklearn doesn't handle nan. see #4725
    if not params.get('eval_metric', True):
        del params['eval_metric']  # don't give as None param to Booster
    return params
```

The dictionary params is apparently not properly defined (the key 'missing' doesn't exist) when XGBClassifier initialization is called in XGB initialization.
Do you have any idea what is the problem or how to track it ?

Thanks

Comment: if there is no entry in the dict `params` such as `'missing'` you'll get `KeyError` by trying to access it. Modify the condition: `if params['missing'] is np.nan:` to: `if params.get('missing', np.nan) is np.nan:` same as you do for `eval_metric`

Comment: The issue is with `params = super(XGBModel, self).get_params(deep=deep)`, which is returning a `dict` that doesn't have what you want.

Comment: That I understood, but why ? That dictionary is created and managed inside the mother class, I didn't touch it, so I don't understand why it is not well defined by the mother class when I use it in a inherited class.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it worked when i initialized all of the mother class parameters, even if the mother class constructor is supposed to have default values for them :

```
class XGB(XGBClassifier):

    def __init__(self,max_depth=3, learning_rate=0.1,
                 n_estimators=100, silent=True,
                 objective="binary:logistic",
                 nthread=-1, gamma=0, min_child_weight=1,
                 max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1,
                 reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1,
                 base_score=0.5, seed=0, missing=None,
                 frac=None,k_neighbors=None,m_neighbors=None,out_step=None):

        if k_neighbors:
            self.balancingStrategy = 'smote'
            self.k_neighbors = k_neighbors
            self.m_neighbors = m_neighbors
            self.out_step = out_step
        elif frac :
            self.balancingStrategy = 'normal'
            self.frac = frac
        else:
            self.balancingStrategy = 'false'


        super(XGB,self).__init__(max_depth, learning_rate,
                                n_estimators, silent, objective,
                                nthread, gamma, min_child_weight,
                                max_delta_step, subsample,
                                colsample_bytree, colsample_bylevel,
                                reg_alpha, reg_lambda,
                                scale_pos_weight, base_score, seed, missing)
```

Not sure I understand the logic here, but it is always good to know :)